# how to remove datapoint from google chart using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using google chart to display the data analysis and i want to remove from google chart the datapoints can any one tell me how to remove datapoint from google chart,as i am coding in javascript and jquery.logic how to proceed this one

```js
<html>
  <head>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart()
   {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Age', 'Weight'],
          [ 8,      12],
          [ 4,      60],
          [ 11,     14],
          [ 10,      80],
          [ 3,      40],
          [ 6.5,    7]
        ]);

        var options =
  {
          title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
          hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
        chart.draw(data, options);
  
  function selectHandler() 
  {
        var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
        var value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row,0);
        alert('The user selected ' + value);
  
  
  var array=[value];
  alert(array);
  alert("want to delete this point " + value);
  
  }
  
 }                                         
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make no sense to remove the data because then the chart wouldn't display.

What you can do it just hide the points in CSS:

```
circle{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want to try this case is it coming or not suppose if user ask this case then i must show that case also so i am looking to delete datapoints